# How to "UPDATE WHEN DUPLICATE ELSE INSERT" when key is not PRIMARY KEY in MySql

Tags: mysql

I know I can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), but how can I do that when the KEY involved is *not* the primary key? For example:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   transId VARCHAR(64),
   pltCode VARCHAR(64),
   val1 VARCHAR(6),
   val2 VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(1,'001','abc','val1','val2');
```

If `transId` and `pltCode` already exist, I would like to update the original record. Otherwise, else insert a new one. What should the SQL look like?

Comment: Search for how to do `upsert` or `merge` in MySQL. If you want someone to help you with a query, then create a fiddle with sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll just need to create a `UNIQUE` index on those two columns first:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`transId`, `pltCode`);
```

Or better yet, create a new table :

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   transId VARCHAR(64),
   pltCode VARCHAR(64),
   val1 VARCHAR(6),
   val2 VARCHAR(6),
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE `unique_index`(`transId`, `pltCode`)
 );
```

> Field Attribute **NOT NULL** is being used because we do not want this
>   field to be NULL. So if the user tries to create a record with NULL
>   value, then MySQL will raise an error.
>
> Field Attribute **AUTO_INCREMENT** tells MySQL to go ahead and add the
>   next available number to the id field. So that you don't have to set it manually every time.
>
> Keyword **PRIMARY KEY** is used to define a column as primary key. You can
>   use multiple columns separated by comma to define a primary key.
>
> Keyword **UNIQUE** means that two rows cannot have the same index
>   value.

Refer [This sitepoint tutorial on table creation for more info:](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-create-tables.htm)

And then do an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to modify the other columns when a duplicate key is received while inserting:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (
  transId, pltCode, val1, val2
) values('001','abc','val1','val2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val1 = new_val1, val2 = new_val2;
```